# Open files without extensions in PDF viewer per default

Tags: windows, filesystems, application-launch

For some reason (backup system, different story) I have a bunch of PDF files without a file name extension.

It is  possible to configuere my PDF viewer as the default application for files without file name extensions (.pdf) ?

(Yes I know, this ist stupid question. It´s more a theoretical question :-)
I know tools like TrID - File Identifier)

Comment: Considering the file system uses extensions to associate file types, how would you associate a program to a file type if the file has no type? You've answered your own question. Honestly, this is not a place for theoretical questioning. Rather for actual problems you face.

Comment: Why not just `ren *. *.pdf`?

Comment: As @techie007 suggested, its better to bulk rename all the files with a single command and give them the appropriate extension than to associate a program as default for files without extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already know all the files that are PDF's but don't have the extension, you should move them all into the same folder and then add the extension to all of these files using a renaming script or something of the like.  this would be much easier than trying to explain to your computer that you want everything without a file type to open in a PDF viewer.

You really want your computer to ask you every time you open a new type of file or a file with no type, other wise you will come to an instance where you have a bunch of files that open in your PDF view and you don't want them to, and you would then have to figure out a way to reverse what you have done for this specific file type.

Just add the extension to these files, it will save you a headache in the long run.